# Overlay text image on scene image in PIL

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, logical-operators

I have a text image and I want to overlay it over a scene image, both having the same size and in `RGB` mode. I have tried the `ImageChops` OR operation but it seems to only work on binary (mode '1'). `ImageChops.add_modulo` and `blend` functions also did not help at all. What I need is to replace the pixel values in the scene image with those from the text image. The text image has 0 (black background) and the text has the value of 255. So, the overlay should be crystal clear, although scene images are in color.

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it as follows:

```
scene_image.paste(text_img, box=None, mask=text_img.convert('1'))
```